# MsDeploy Skip Root Web Config deployment only

Tags: batch-file, iis, iis-8, msdeploy

I am using Ms-deploy for Web Deployment.

Below command i am using for this

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="${p:resource/work.dir}${p:component.name}\%BinariesMode%%DirectoryOffset%" -dest:contentPath=%1,ComputerName=localhost -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -enableRule:Donotdeleterule -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="\\Web\.config$"
```

It not only skip the web config of root folder but also of View folder web.config also.

How can i overcome this issue.
I don't want to use Full path of web config.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
absolutePath="(?<!Views)\\Web\.config"
```

Comment: I want to exclude all the folder not only View. I have load Balance and other folders as well.So how can i skip root config deployment only.

Comment: You could try using the root folder name like this - absolutePath="MyProjectName\\Web\.config"

Comment: I tested this and it did work.  Started with "\\Web\.config$" and neither config was copied.  Then changed to "WebApplication2\\Web\.config$" and it only copied the Views web.config.

Comment: It's still not working, please refer to attached screen shot. marketsworkflowdev is the name of vdir and i have config file under pawan & root folders.

Comment: Try changing "MyProjectName\\Web\.config" to "MyProjectName\\web\.config".  Notice the lower case "w".

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I have replicated this scenario on my machine and it works.  Sorry.