# MSdeploy skip root webconfig

Tags: msdeploy

I was able to skip deploying webconfig on root folder by following approach 
[MsDeploy Skip Root Web Config deployment only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919879/msdeploy-skip-root-web-config-deployment-only)

However i have another folder containing web.config apart from "views" folder which needs to be negated from skip arguement.
I tried following which seems to be incorrect regular expression and didnot work

```
absolutePath="(?<!Views|Configs)\\Web\.config"
```

where Configs is the folder containing webconfig file. what should be right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by this

```
absolutePath="(?<!Views)(?<!Configs)\\Web\.config"
```